# postgresql 13 gen_salt not a function

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql v13.2 andlooking to replace importing the bcrypt package with using pgcrypto and 'bf'alogithm.

The attached is using pgAdmin

I get the error ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist

The installed pgcrypto version is 1.3

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Example code:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (
 'johndoe@mail.com', 
 crypt('johnspassword', gen_salt('bf'))  
);
```

Error message:
ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist
LINE 3:   crypt('johnspassword', gen_salt('bf'))  );
^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 95

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable the crypto function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>  email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
>  password TEXT NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (
>  'johndoe@mail.com', 
>  crypt('johnspassword', gen_salt('bf'))  
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist
> ```

LINE 3:  crypt('johnspassword', gen_salt('bf'))
^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

> 

## Run this for every database, you use crypto functions

> ```
> CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (
>  'johndoe@mail.com', 
>  crypt('johnspassword', gen_salt('bf'))  
> );
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=22de5402dbd5355df3891cf8ad958d05)*